# My AppEngine Application is too slow, how to speedup the application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

I am developing an AppEngine application with GWT framework using Java. Objectify as back-end(storage purpose). Application has around 30 modules. Whenever I open any page in my web application, it is too slow to display. I want my application faster.

Please help me out with this nasty problem.

Comment: Profile it and look for which modules/functions are slow.

Comment: All modules in application are too slow. I guess, For first time to download the java script it may caused to slow. Is there any solution to avoid this problem also. Not only first time, but also some times (cannot examine the particular time) getting slow.

Comment: @satyarao did my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

Two back to back steps.

Here is the [SpeedTracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/get-started)

And here is the [Optimization Techniques of GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOptimizing)

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned above, do this steps in general.

but developing for AppEngine needs thinking for AppEngine.
so also AppEngine Docu:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#What_Is_A_Loading_Request

Main stuff: AppEngine is not a Java App Server like, Tomcat, Jboss and so on.
AppEngine is a complete own environment running java, (this you should at latest realize when you downloaded the AppEngine SDK )

and then you should see two options, change your account to billing account, and pay for preloaded App

or better, forgot about third party libs and write it by yourself,
for what you need objectify ??? the appengine datastore api is very good.
using the Apis directly will also point your thinking of how to design your app for AppEngine better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) to profile your application and identity which RPCs are slowing down your app.

Having done this, you should be able to find ways to reduce the number of RPCs you're making, e.g. by using [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache). You could also try to use async [APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async) wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should think to cache data for the session or across sessions on your client side also. You can do statistics on the most common requests and do server caching on them too

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain the reason its slow is because your application loads all the code in the browser.

Use [HTTP watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) tool to see whether this is correct. For a 2MB nocache.js file it usually takes 2 minutes to load.

Are you using any MVP framework on your application; if not, this could be one of the problem. Objectify is not going to slow you application, I presume it is the way you built your application.

Also try to use GWT 2.5, so you can take advantage of the closure compiler so you can reduce you application's footprint for about 20% (maybe). Furthermore if you are deploying in Tomcat, you can try to enable gzip compression.

"Slowness" of an application can't be attributed to just one part of the application, it could be spread across the layers of your application (based on my experience)

Hope this helps.